# Background image padding from right

Tags: html, css

How can I set a background image on right side of a div and set the padding from right side without defining the fixed distance from left? For example I want to set an image to on the right side of the div and always have 20px padding from right.

The width of the div is not always same, thats why I can not define exact position. I just want it to have exact 20px padding on right side, no matter what is width of the div.

I am trying following code, but it does not work.

**HTML:**

```
<div>Title</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div{
  background: url(gowalla.png) no-repeat right center;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;  
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/mQGcF/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it with `background-position: 96% 50% ;`

first value indicates `x-axis` and the second one `y-axis`.

[**SEE THIS LINK**](http://userinterfacehome.blogspot.in/2012/08/paddingmargin-for-background-images-in.html) for the explanation.

```
 div{
  background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/35-Sweet-social-icons/32/gowalla.png) no-repeat 96% 50% ;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;  
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mQGcF/9/)**

---

**Updated Answer**

Try adding an outer div and specify margin to the inner div

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap"><div>Title</div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .wrap{
        border:solid 1px green; 
      display:inline-block;  
      width:auto; 
    }
    .wrap div{ 
      width: 400px;  
      background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/35-Sweet-social-icons/32/gowalla.png) right no-repeat;  
      margin-right: 20px; 
      padding:20px
    }
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/mQGcF/7/)**

Comment: I feel sure the question needed to achieve this without setting a specific left position?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't do this with CSS. There are only two options for you:

- Include the spacing in the image. This may not be possible, but is the simplest if it is.
- Use two containing `DIV` tags. One holds the border, and the outer spacing, the second holds the background.

  ```
  <div class="outer"><div class="inner">Title</div>
  ```

And CSS

```
.outer{
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 0px 20px;  
}
.inner{
    background: url('gowalla.png') no-repeat right center;
    padding: 20px 0px;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mQGcF/4/

Comment: I thing it will be a problem when you specify the width to outer div, as OP has mentioned width is not fixed.

Comment: The width is simply copied from the original example. You can change it to whatever you like, or take it out completely - the background will still be positioned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

U can use

```
padding-right:20px;
```

or

```
 padding:0px 20px 0px 0px;
```

demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mQGcF/5/)

Comment: img{  width:100; height:100px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:20px;}

Comment: that is bg image, not inline image

Comment: in inline image give <img src:"url" style=" padding-right:20px;"/> simple

Comment: :) leave it.. OP is asking for bg padding solution.